# how can I assign the dataframe data types to a variable in rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

how can I assign the dataframe data types to a variable in rpy2?

The way I would do this in in Python is:

dt = df.dtypes 
print(dt)

I have already tried the following in rpy2:

dt <- str(df) 
print(dt)

but I get the following R Parsing error:

in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/_rinterface_capi.py in _parse(cdata, num, rmemory)
650     # PARSE_EOF
651     if status[0] != openrlib.rlib.PARSE_OK:
--> 652         raise RParsingError('Parsing status not OK',
653                             status=PARSING_STATUS(status[0]))
654     return res

RParsingError: Parsing status not OK - PARSING_STATUS.PARSE_ERROR

Answer (score 0):

The parsing error was caused by the comment line at the beginning of the cell. rpy2 does not like the use of comments that begin and end with '''.
'''